# Get network status with Java

Tags: java, network-programming

I built an automatic driving RC-Car, which should stop instantly, if there is no connection to the wifi.

Is there any possibility to get the status of the network connection with Java? (connected/not connected)

I think, that I could ping the host every second, until the connection is lost. But I hope, there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't know of a way of getting notified about connection state changes via an event, so you'll have to use polling.

The simplest way is probably a periodic invocation of `InetAddress.isReachable()` (documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29)). It (typically) uses pings under the hood, so it should give you a fairly quick answer.

Alternatively, you can use a dedicated system call such as windows's [InternetGetConnectedState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Call it using JNI and return a boolean.

Comment: It only uses pings on *nix platforms if running as root. Otherwise it tries to connect a TCP socket to the echo port.